# Serialize an object to XML Element (c#)

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute("player", IsNullable = false)]
 public class Player
 {
  ...
  }
```

Creating and serializing new Player() whitout setting any properties gives me 
the XML Element`<player/>` but I would like to get `<player></player>.`

Comment: can you explain what you want a bit better?

Comment: <player/> is a short form for <player></player>. The XML serialization of your class is valid.

Answer (score 0):

As far as XML is concerned, `<player/>` is equivalent to `<player></player>`. See XML spec [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags) related to this.

If you **still** need to have `<player></player>` then you are doing something **wrong**.

Comment: sometimes it isn't you ... it is your consumers and well... the customer is always correct.

Comment: They are not! **Customer is not right when they ignore the industry standards.** Tell them use an `XML parser`. That is what I do in company I work for. Show them XML spec and tell them they are WRONG!!!

Comment: You cannot do this in XML, using XML serialiser since as far as XML is concerned, they are the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your problem is when you read an empty node you are crashing. You should always check for empty elements before trying to read any elements/attributes.

Answer (score 0):

They should be considered equivalent values. However, if you need  then working with a custom XmlWriter may be your best bet, as described here in the answer to a similar question here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/979315cf-6727-4979-a554-316218ab8b24/